# Is there any way to perform an inner join for a many relation using go BUN library?

Tags: postgresql, go, bun

Having a model relation, with a many relation defined as below

```
type TableA struct {
   ID int
   Name string
   TableBs []*TableB  `bun:"rel:has-many,join:id=table_aid"`
 }
```

```
type TableB struct{
  ID int
  TableAID int
  Num int
}
```

Is there any way to perform an inner join using ORM Relation, in order to exclude TableA elements without TableB elements that suit one condition??

The following query gets TablaA elements with nil TableBs field, and there is no way to exclude them:

```
db.NewSelect().Model(tablaA).Relation("TableBs", func(q *bun.SelectQuery) *bun.SelectQuery {
            return q.Where("num = 1")
        })
```